# Can someone canonically differentiate between scrollTop and scrollHeight?

Tags: javascript, html

For example,

```
function fnCheckScroll(){   
    var iNewHeight = oDiv.scrollHeight;
    var iscrolTop = oDiv.scrollTop; 
    alert("The value of the scrollHeight property is: "  + iNewHeight + "px"); 
    alert("The value of the scrollTop property is: " + iscrolTop + "px");        
}

<div id="oDiv" style="overflow: scroll; height= 100px; width= 250px; text-align: left">
Hello<br>
</div>
```

In IE 8, the value of scrollTop is always: 0 - returns 0 for scrollTop (even after scrolling)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If I scroll down 5px in this window, the window's `scrollTop` value is 5. If I scroll right 10px in a scrollable div, the div's `scrollLeft` value is 10.

When I scroll to the top left corner of this window, both its `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` values are 0.

Comment: Does scrollTop property is supported by IE8?

Comment: @Lakshman: I'm pretty sure every modern browser, and even older browsers like IE6, support this method.

Answer (score 93):

[image]

Ref: [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop), [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight), [clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight)

Answer (score 34):

See the MDC articles, [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollTop) and [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollHeight).  In summary, scrollTop is how much it's currently scrolled, and scrollHeight is the total height, including content scrolled out of view.

Comment: How about the browser support of above properties, does all browser support same property? specifically in IE 8?

Comment: They were introduced by MS in IE4, and are still non-standard.  All modern browsers should support them, but Opera apparently gives incorrect values for scrollHeight.  See [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t35).

Comment: Also, they are [being specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#scroll-attributes) in CSSOM View Module, a W3C working draft.

Answer (score 0):

In Safari 6.0.1 the scrollHeight gives the height of the control and not the total height including content scrolled out of view. So it cannot be used to find the total height required to show without a scroll bar.