# how to get full window height when there is a scroll bar?

Tags: jquery

var window_height = $( window ).height(); this is giving current window height not the full height including scroll height. I want full window height including scroll height.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940006/what-is-scrolltop-and-scrollheight

Comment: try $('body').prop('scrollHeight')

Comment: $(document).height();

Answer (score 9):

You should check this link: 
[How to get height of entire document with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/how-to-get-height-of-entire-document-with-javascript)

```
    var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;

var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                       html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
```

Answer (score 3):

**As of 2020** the best way to find the height of an entire document is:

```
document.documentElement.scrollHeight
```

Credit: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44077777/5072015) on another question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is

```
$("body").height()
```

Comment: Nope - visible only.  One of my divs is much more.  I want the total of everything in and out of view.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
function getheight(){
    var d= document.documentElement;
    var b= document.body;
    var who= d.offsetHeight? d: b ;
    return Math.max(who.scrollHeight,who.offsetHeight);
}
getheight()
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me - all gave viewport-height.  I had to wrap the entire page in a div (class 'wrapper'), then get it with:

```
    $('.wrapper').prop('scrollHeight');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(document).height();` to get full height with scrollable area.

Use `$(window).height();` to get only viewable area height.

**Important :** The *document* height is the entire height of the whole document, even what is outside the viewable area. The *window* height is just the viewable area.